# For a convergent iterated function, is the distance between the nth iteration and the fixed point always decreasing as n increases?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems, iterated-function-system

Suppose we have a function $f$ that has a fixed point $\tau$. Let's also consider a real number $x_0$, that, when we infinitely apply the function $f$ to it, it converges towards $\tau$.

Also, $x_0$ is inside the biggest monotonic interval of $f$ that contains $\tau$, such that $f(x_0)$ is also inside that interval, and so on.

I just wonder if, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, |f^{n+1}(x_0)-\tau|<|f^{n}(x_0)-\tau|$

With the initial conditions. Or if it isn't, what are the restrictions so that it is true?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f : [0,1) \to [0,1)$ defined by
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
0&t = 0\\
\frac1k  & \frac 1{k+1} \le t < \frac1k, k\text{ odd}\\
\frac1{k+3} & \frac 1{k+1} \le t < \frac1k, k\text{ even}
\end{cases}$$

Note that for any $x\in(0,1), f^n(x)$ converges to $0$, but it is never decreasing. Instead it alternates between smaller increases and larger decreases.

This is just one simple example. You can vary the idea to make $f$ continuous, or even analytic, and to be defined on all $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I think you misunderstood something. I wasn't talking about the number being larger or smaller, but the distance to Tau being decreasing.

Comment: That part I did not misunderstand. Since $\tau = 0$ in this example, "larger or smaller" is exactly the same as "distance from $\tau$ increasing or decreasing". The example shows that $|f^n(x_0)-\tau|$ in general need not ever become decreasing, even when $\tau$ is an attractor. However, there is a different issue I missed: your requirement that "$x_0$ is inside the biggest monotonic interval of $f$ that contains $\tau$." In this example, the only "monotonic interval of $f$ that contains $\tau$" is $[0, 0]$, So that requires $x_0 = 0$, and $f^n(x_0)$ is constant.